# Why does Java *sort* HashMap entries even though it shouldn't?

Tags: java, collections

A `HashMap` in Java shouldn't be sorted, and doesn't guarantee order. Its order can be changed throughout the lifecycle of the application and if you want a sorted map, you should use a `LinkedHashMap`, or better yet, a `TreeMap`.

I *know this*, have experienced this, and this is confirmed by the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

However, I've just wrote some code that just *won't* keep the `HashMap` *unsorted*. At first, I thought it was fluke coincidence, but I ran the code many times and *the same* output is shown.

```java
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("A", 99.5);
map.put("B", 67.4);
map.put("C", 67.4);
map.put("D", 67.3);

System.out.println("Unsorted map: " + map);
```

This results in:

```
Unsorted map: {A=99.5, B=67.4, C=67.4, D=67.3}
```

I assumed that the `String` keys got sorted lexicographically, somehow, since they followed `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, though, here's another example where the sorted `String` keys aren't necessarily sorted by lexicographical value:

```java
Map<String, Integer> unsortedMap = new HashMap();

unsortedMap.put("David", 21);
unsortedMap.put("Scott", 34);
unsortedMap.put("Marcus", 31);
unsortedMap.put("Vladimir", 24);

unsortedMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

And this one results in:

```
Marcus=31
David=21
Vladimir=24
Scott=34
```

`Marcus` is lexicographically greater than `David`, but `David` is lexicographically *less* than `Vladimir`.

I assume that this part of the source code specifically is responsible for this:

```
static int tieBreakOrder(Object a, Object b) {
    int d;
    if (a == null || b == null ||
        (d = a.getClass().getName().
         compareTo(b.getClass().getName())) == 0)
        d = (System.identityHashCode(a) <= System.identityHashCode(b) ?
             -1 : 1);
    return d;
}
```

**Note:** I'm running Java 15, though, rolling back to older versions, such as Java 8 didn't change the behavior at all.

Comment: You used single-letter keys, which hash to their ASCII values.  In general, hash values won't change from run to run, but may change from version to version.  This is what "unspecified behavior" means.  If you write code based on how it works today, but that behavior is unspecified, that code _may_ break in the future... or may continue to work for 30 years until suddenly it doesn't.

Comment: I am always amazed how often on Stack Overflow a valid, well-written, thorough, and interesting Question like this one receives a down-vote.

Comment: « A `HashMap` in Java shouldn't be sorted » Not true. Both `Map` and `HashMap` make no specific guarantees as to their order. That does not mean *unordered*. They may be ordered or not ordered. Internal management of ordering is an implementation detail, and is none of my business as a calling programmer. Though your Question and the solution are interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right with assuming `String` keys got sorted - but it is not lexicographically sorted but based on hash of the key.
Method `java.util.HashMap#put` uses method `java.util.HashMap#hash` for calculating hash of key - `String` in our case.
Results of `java.util.HashMap#hash` for letter A - 65, letter B - 66, letter C - 67 and so on up for single-letter objects (checked for A-Za-z, can't say anything about other values).
Result of `java.util.HashMap#hash` for David - 65805752.

Calculated hash is then used to decide the index of bucket in underlying array `java.util.HashMap#table` in the method `java.util.HashMap#putVal`. Exact part of code:

```
p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]
```

Which effectively takes proper index of array based on hash value.

So, yeah - order of entries not guaranteed - but it can be manipulated by knowing the exact size of underlying array of nodes and knowing hashcode of keys that are to be put into map